Configuration Raspberry Pi IoT LoRa pHAT with LoRa® (Multi Frequency) with Raspberry Pi 5
I bought Raspberry Pi IoT LoRa pHAT with LoRa® (Multi Frequency) - link below:
https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/iot-lora-node-phat-for-raspberry-pi?srsltid=AfmBOoqC9ez_LDpq8qtBaLkOt2jfOPNUSKTv3eLv60Xx46fyTg8aj-zF
I wanted to configure it with Raspberry Pi 5 according to guide from link below:
https://learn.pi-supply.com/make/getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi-lora-node-phat/
Step 5 contains directive to change /boot/config.txt (insert dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt).
Unfurtunetely, I got an error with following messagae after a reboot: "dterror:overlay 'miniuart-bt' is not supported on the 'bcm2712' platform"  and warning "dtwarn:overlay 'pi3-miniuart-bt' has been renamed 'miniuart-bt' ".
I don't know RPi5 well enough and I don't have an idea to resolve this issue. If somebody had configured it with RPi5 properly or know how do it well I will be grateful for help.

For some bizarre reason a number of tutorials recommend turning off the fully featured UART (connected to Bluetooth).
This MAY have made some sense IF you have a Pi3, have some pressing NEED for the fully featured UART and don't use Bluetooth BUT was unnecessary for most users.
If you want to use LoRa which should have no such need; ignore it or look for a better tutorial. Ideally you should use a Pi5 tutorial as there are (poorly documented) changes in the hardware which differ from earlier models.
There is no reason on Pi4 or Pi5 which have a number of fully featured UARTs available for use and Pi5 uses a dedicated UART for Bluetooth.

Raspberry Pi 5 does not have mini UART.

